# Add to Cart Button On Catalog Search Grid Broken

Tags: php, html, magento, search

I have a magento store where the Add to Cart button has stopped working and instead a search query is performed ( where the & are changed to &amp so it doesn't even work ) This can be seen by adding a item to cart here: http://bit.ly/1o8SwmE

This add to cart button does however work on category grid pages. I have tried pasting  the link generated in the form into a web browser and it also redirects me to the same broken search page, I have also tried pasting the action link from the add to cart form on a working category grid page into firebug on the non working page and this then adds the product from the category page perfectly.

The snippets of code i have used are pasted below and other people have had them working it seems so this may not be the issue.

```
    OLD CODE
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('QTY') ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="new-qty-cat" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button class="new-qty-button" type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"></button>
</form>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    NEW CODE
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
    <input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" />
    <button class=form-button" onclick="productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> var productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?> = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>');    productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>.submit = function(){ if (this.validator.validate()) {    this.form.submit(); }   }.bind(productAddToCartForm_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>);</script>

    NEW CODE 2
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
</form>


    New Code 3
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
<input class="new-qty-cat" type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<button type="button" class="new-qty-button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span>   </span></span></button>
   </form>
```

Comment: on the link you provide, I have the behavior you describe but not the code you paste. Are you making test or can it be that you don't have on production the code you created ?

Comment: Hello, Currently i am testing different codes and trying to work out a solution so may have changed slightly but the problem is the same. I will paste the code in my file again above as new code 3

Comment: I think you'd better search with a recently installed module or js library because I have an (ugly) JS error that probably blocks everything.